# How can I upgrade an application from new source?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I am runnign debian wheezy. I have PHP 5.4 installed from default repos. And now I have added these to sources list to upgrade to PHP 5.6

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

And I have added the key:

```
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- |apt-key add -
```

Now if I run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I will see

> The following packages have been kept back:   php5-cgi php5-cli
>   php5-common php5-curl php5-fpm php5-imagick php5-mysql

I know that if I first remove php5-fpm and then reinstall it I will end up with new PHP 5.6.

### Question

Is there a way to perform the upgrade without first removing the packages?

Comment: try `apt-get dist-upgrade`